# Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state, mount, react-draft-wysiwyg

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the o component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
import { convertToHTML } from "draft-convert";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false },
);
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import styles from "./Editor.module.scss";

const TextEditor = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [wordCount, setWordCount] = useState("0");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty(),
  );
  const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
  };
  const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    setData(state.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());
    convertContentToHTML();
    setWordCount(data.length);
    // console.log(data);
    console.log(state);
  };

  const convertContentToHTML = () => {
    let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
  };

  //   const createMarkup = (html) => {
  //     return {
  //       __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html),
  //     };
  //   };

  return (
    <div className={styles.editor__wrapper}>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        wrapperClassName={styles.wrapper_class}
        editorClassName={`${styles.editor_class} ${
          clicked && styles.expand__editor_size
        }`}
        toolbarClassName={styles.toolbar_class}
        localization={{
          locale: "ko",
        }}
        // toolbarOnFocus
        toolbar={{
          options: [
            "fontFamily",
            "blockType",
            "fontSize",
            "inline",
            "list",
            "textAlign",
            "colorPicker",
            "link",
            "embedded",
            "emoji",
            "image",
            "remove",
            "history",
          ],
        }}
        onFocus={(event) => {}}
      />
      <div className={styles.btn__wrapper}>
        <button className={styles.fullscreen__btn} onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={styles.icon} /> 전체화면
        </button>
        <span className={styles.word__count}>: {wordCount}</span>
      </div>
      <div
        className="preview"
        // dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(convertedContent)}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

> I am getting this warning when I use react-draft-wysiwyg editor with react funtional component. How can I fix it Please help